# How to get Ivy to not delete a file (or include it locally)

Tags: ant, ivy

My project is build by Ant/Ivy. Ivy is deleting a library (self made) that I need and I don't have a repo for it. How do I configure my ivy that it either doesn't delete files that are not specified OR make a local dependency on the ivy cache?

Answer (score 0):

For Ivy, any dependency has to come from a 'resolver'. So even if you don't have a classical remote repository to host a self made library, you should "publish" that library in a repository.

Ivy is very flexible on how to resolve dependencies in a repository. For a simple adhoc library dependency, you can set a specific folder in your project to be a local repository, and have Ivy resolve dependencies in there.

In your `ivysettings.xml`, you should then add a resolver for a 'local' folder in which you can put your library:

```
<ivysettings>
  <resolvers>
    <filesystem name="local-libs">
      <artifact pattern="local/[module]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
    </filesystem>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

With this piece of settings, considering that in the `ivy.xml` file of your project you have also declared a dependency on that self made library, Ivy will resolve the dependency tree properly.

More options on a local filesystem resolver can be found in the documentation: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0/resolver/filesystem.html